# :dets.open_file argument error

Tags: elixir

```
iex(1)> :dets.open_file(:storage, [{:type, :set}])           
{:ok, :storage}
```

When I try to use other argument, which should be perfectly fine regarding Erlang documentation:

```
iex(2)> :dets.open_file(:storage, [{:type, :set}, {:file, "file"}])
** (ArgumentError) argument error
```

UPD:

```
iex(4)> :dets.open_file(:storage, [{:type, :set}, {:file, 'file'}])
{:error, :incompatible_arguments}
```

Comment: Try single quote for the file name. Most Erlang APIs expect a charlist for file paths.

Comment: @Dogbert, still error but seems to be closer

Comment: Could you try it in a new `iex` session? It seems like the error is due to you creating a DETS with the same name but no file earlier.

Comment: @Dogbert, yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
:dets.open_file('file', [{:type, :set}])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
:dets.open_file(:storage, [{:type, :set}, {:file, String.to_atom("file")}])
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.